# How can I pause the console window in .pl and .bat file?

Tags: perl, batch-file

As I know, when I run **cs myConsoleApp.cs** from windows command line, I can pause the Console Window by add the code below:

`Console.ReadLine();`

Then How can I pause Console Window in myConsoleApp.pl and myConsoleApp.bat? I just want to monitor the running result from the Console window. Thank you.

Suppose myConsoleApp.bat like this:

```
taskkill /f /im "E1.exe"
taskkill /f /im "E2.exe"

pause
```

Suppose myConsoleApp.pl like this:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

print "Hello World!";

<>;
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

`pause` for .bat

and

```
<>; #Read from STDIN
```

for Perl

Comment: Better to use <STDIN> - <> might be the input from a file (eg if you ran " x.pl file1 file2"

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about in perl, but in a batch file it's easy:

```
pause
```

The help for this command states:

> Suspends processing of a batch program
>   and displays the message
>   **Press any key to continue . . .**

Answer (score 0):

`<>` for Perl works great. And yeah, pause is convenient for cmd.