# Not able see error or ouput when running perl script?

Tags: perl

perl output screen closed quickly that's why i'm unable to see any error msg at all. but by opening perl through cmd only can see. Is there any method to pause output screen like in batch ?..

[How can I pause the console window in .pl and .bat file?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2513682/how-can-i-pause-the-console-window-in-pl-and-bat-file)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you're on Windows, open CMD window first ("Start"->"Run"->"cmd.exe")

Also, you can pipe the command output to "`|more`" command on both Windows and Unix

If you're on some other environment, you need to explain WHERE and HOW you're executing your Perl script

Comment: nw I'm able see error and output screen by opening script through cmd only.

Answer (score 2):

If you want your script to wait for user input before exiting, you can add this in anywhere in the script:

```
END { <STDIN> }
```

Using the END block will handle multiple exit points (for example dying from an error).

Comment: It only working when full code is write otherwise i cant see any error at all

Comment: It wont work @AKHolland

Comment: I'm can see error msg only when i open though cmd

Answer (score 0):

You don't state it, but I suspect you're running the script from a GUI. Open a shell window (bash or command.com) and run the script from the command line. That will keep the output around long enough to examine.